# How to modify lapply() to run in parralel?

Tags: r

I'm learning regression model, basically I need to run regression model for a list of alpha paramteres. Because my data size is very large, the computation time is very high. 
How can I make my code run in parallel for different value of alpha.
Here is the bottleneck of my code and I want to make this part to run in parallel. Can someone help me with that?

```
elasticnet<-try(lapply(alphaslist, function(x){cv.glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha=x, nfolds=10,standardize=TRUE,parallel= TRUE)}))
                 if(class(elasticnet) == "try-error") next;
```

Here is my code :

```
 alphaslist<-seq(0,1,by=0.001)
 elasticnet<-try(lapply(alphaslist, function(x){cv.glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha=x, nfolds=10,standardize=TRUE,parallel= TRUE)}))
                 if(class(elasticnet) == "try-error") next;
                 for (j in 1:length(alphaslist)) {A[j]<-min(elasticnet[[j]]$cvm)}

                  index<-which(A==min(A), arr.ind=TRUE)
                   #Alpha<- alphaslist[index]
                 Best_model_ENET[[i]]<- elasticnet[[index]]
```

Comment: see `parallel::mclapply`

Comment: Example does not run as given. Could you supply some data for a reproducible example? This includes things that might seem obvious to you, such as `require(glmnet)`. However you might want to look at `parallels::mclapply()` first.